# Array shortcut in apple generated code

Tags: objective-c, xcode, syntax

I just started a new project in xCode and saw this lines in the app delegate:

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2];
```

I understand this is an array but It is new to me in Obj-C.

Can anybody explain where this syntax coming from ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [new syntax](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) that has been recently added to Objective C. There is also a new syntax for `NSNumber`s, `NSDictionary`s, and accessing arrays with square brackets:

```
NSNumber *fortyTwo = @42;

NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"key1" : @1.23,  @"key2" : @4.56};

NSMutableArray *array = ...;
id newObject = ...;
array[123] = newObject;
```

Comment: Thanks, Is that a compiler dependent only or in other words will it run on older iOS ?

Comment: @shannoga My understanding is that this is syntactic sugar, so it should run on all iOS for which you could produce an executable with the set of tools that support the new syntax.